# Поиск объекта в сессии Sprign MVC @Scope

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc, сессия

При каждом запросе модели Accaunt постоянно осуществляется поиск в БД. Хочу инициализировать его всего один раз. Я правильно реализовал или нет? и будут ли ошибки при загрузке сервлетов, ведь `private Accaunt accaunt` не имеет `@Scope`.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.work.controller.accaunt")
public class CtrAddAccaunt {

    @Autowired private DaoAccaunt daoAccaunt;

    private Accaunt accaunt;

    @ModelAttribute(SessionAttr.ACCAUNT) 
    public Accaunt getAccaunt(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("поиск аккаунта + "+authentication.getName());
        if (accaunt != null) {
            return accaunt;
        } else {
            return daoAccaunt.getAccaunt(authentication.getName());
        }        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас `private Accaunt accaunt;` не используется вообще.

Полагаю, вы хотели сделать так:

```
@ModelAttribute(SessionAttr.ACCAUNT) 
public Accaunt getAccaunt(Authentication authentication) {
    System.out.println("поиск аккаунта + "+authentication.getName());
    if (accaunt == null) {
        account = daoAccaunt.getAccaunt(authentication.getName());
    }
    return account;        
}
```

Но эта реализация сохранит account один раз - а вам нужно сохранять account для каждого authentication.getName() - использовать HashMap, например.

Не работал подробно с MVC, но, думаю, всё равно так работать не будет.
@Scope нужно указывать над классом CrtAddAccount, чтобы добиться нужного эффекта. Но могут возникнуть другие проблемы..

**Лучшее решение в вашем случае** - использование spring cache.
[Вот пример](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) его использования при обращении к БД
А вот [краткое описание на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818285/how-should-i-implement-a-cache-object-system-in-spring/26825843#26825843)

П.С. Однако необходимость использования кэширования обращения к базе возникает не часто, думаю, стоит её использовать с осторожностью и пониманием дела

Comment: только что решил и ровно в секунды вы ответили)))

Comment: ответ есть выше, если интересно посмотрите.

Comment: все равно спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в том, что `@ControllerAdvice` добовлял ко всем контроллерам в пакете атрибут `ACCAUNT`.

Нужно было просто указать не пакет, а конкретные контроллеры в переменную `assignableTypes`:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {
    CtrAccauntPageUser.class,
    CtrAccauntPageCompany.class
})
public class CtrAdviceAccaunt {

    @Autowired private DaoAccaunt daoAccaunt;

    @ModelAttribute(SessionAttr.ACCAUNT) 
    public Accaunt getAccaunt(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("httpServletRequest + "+request.getRequestURI());
        return daoAccaunt.getAccaunt(authentication.getName());       
    }
}
```

Теперь **`@ModelAttribute(SessionAttr.ACCAUNT)`** виден только в тех контроллерах, которые я указал.

Можно сделать вывод, что:

1. **basePackages** - для сканирования пакета и добавления `@ModelAttribute` во все контроллеры находящиеся в данном пакете;
2. **basePackagesClasses** - для сканирования родительского пакета указанного контроллера и добавления `@ModelAttribute` во все контроллеры находящиеся в данном пакете;
3. **assignableTypes** - для добавления `@ModelAttribute` в конкретный контроллер.